# Converting a 16 Bit decimal into a 2-bit with two's complement in MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: binary, decimal, converters, mips, twos-complement

Excuse me, I am trying to type in the number such as a negative number like this :     -123

Here is what I have typed in so far:

```
.data
putin: .asciiz "Enter the 16 bit decimal number: "
decimalbit: .asciiz "\nThe Decimal is: "
binarybit: .asciiz "\nThe Binary is: "

.text
main:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, putin
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t0, $v0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, decimalbit
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall
```

Can some give me pointers on how I should do it?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem? What's not working?

Comment: I am trying to use someting similar to % from textpad to get a remainder.

Comment: What do you think "bit" is here?

Comment: I need to know what is a substitute for % . I know that div replaces / for dividing and mulo replaces this symbol * for multiplying.

Comment: `div` is used for the remainder as well. Look it up in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_. Of course, if you want to get the remainder of `X / (2^N)` then you can just do a bitwise AND with `(2^N)-1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` stores the remainder in `$HI`. The result can be used with `mfhi`.